# PHP having issues dealing with parsed URL from XML

Tags: php, xml, nusoap

I am receiving results via a webservice running on NUSOAP 0.7.3 and PHP 4.4.9. The XML request is deserialized into an array which has an element containing the URL:

http://results-demo.talegent.co.nz/DesktopModules/Platform/RateVideo.aspx?VID=/////2MAAAAJc2NyZWVuaW5nDTc2ZjVlNTY3LWVmODUxAAAAAAA=

I can echo this URL out fine but as soon as i try to perform any operations on such as assign as an argument to a function my script fails.

The issue appears to be related to length and characters of the value of VID.
If i shorten the value to e.g. '2MAAAAJc2NyZWVuaW5nDTc2ZjVlN' and remove the forward slashes and equals sign on the end it works fine. So is there a maximum length on the value of VID and should the query string be encoded before being sent through in the xml request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post relevant code that breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the VID to your function using urlencode() and then unencode it on the function end. Without seeing your function I can't be any more specific.

```
    $var = urlencode("VID=/////2MAAAAJc2NyZWVuaW5nDTc2ZjVlNTY3LWVmODUxAAAAAAA=");

someFunction($var)
 {
    $url = "http://results-demo.talegent.co.nz/DesktopModules/PlatformRateVideo.aspx?VID=".urldecode($var);   
 }
```

See at PHPFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/vfi-yee

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue by exploding URL on question mark and globalling the resultant array instead of passing through to function as argument. Not pretty but it works.